# Get google translate dropdown selected language in PHP

Tags: php, google-translate

I am using Google translate dropdown on my website where user can select any language and after that when user navigate the google translate keep translating pages automatically to selected language.

I want to save selected language on every page load. So how can I get selected language in google translate using PHP. I know they are saving it somewhere in session, but cant find out how to access that.

I am using this one: http://translate.google.com/manager/website/

Comment: **$_SESSION['lang'] = $_POST['lang'']** can be used in storing a session. You can get the sessions in any page using **$_SESSION['lang']** . You must set session _start(); before you output anything to the browser in all your pages

Comment: @Abolarinstephen When I select language from google translate dropdown, after that every page of website get translated to selected language automatically. I just want to now in which language the user is viewing the pages. I want to select that language in PHP varibale. But question is how will I get google translate selected language. Your $_POST['lang'] I tried but not working.

Comment: You have to do some digging and check to see what Google translate is using to store user preference but if I guess correctly it would be a cookie. If it is a cookie you need to know the cookie name. If you get the cookie name you can refer to it using the $_COOKIE['cookie_name']. To get the cookie name. Open your site in chrome and open the chrome dev tools type this command in the console: `document.cookie()`

Comment: @Abolarinstephen Thank you very much. I used Edit this cookie plugin and it showed all the cookies. Cookie name is *googtrans*. Now I am getting the language code.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. I have added it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do some digging and check to see what Google translate is using to store user preference but if I guess correctly it would be a cookie. If it is a cookie you need to know the cookie name. If you get the cookie name you can refer to it using the $_COOKIE['cookie_name'].

To get the cookie name:

- Open your site in chrome
- Open the chrome developer tools
- Click on console
- Type this command:

  `document.cookie`

The cookie name and values would be in pair. Then you can reference the cookie name using **$_COOKIE['cookie_name']** to get its value.

**OR**

You can install **EditThisCookie** extension in chrome to easily view cookie details